# a bytes-like object is required, not '_io.BufferedReader'

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to load the dumped files, using the following code:

```
cols = None
with open('./experiments/columns.p', 'rb') as p:
    cols = pkl.loads(p).read()
```

but i get this error instead:

> "a bytes-like object is required, not '_io.BufferedReader' "

Comment: `cols = pkl.loads(p.read())`

Answer (score 6):

You're using `pickle`, so you should use the `pickle.load` function:

```
import pickle

with open('./experiments/columns.p', 'rb') as p:
    cols = pickle.load(p)
```

This is less likely to trigger a `MemoryError`.